# Как удалить элемент префаба, вошедший в триггер

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть GameObject, на него брошен скрипт, на котором выполняется `Instantiate`, который объявлен в переменную `ob`.

```
public class spawnPrefabs : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] item = new GameObject[5];

    public GameObject ob;

    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(Inst());
    }

    IEnumerator Inst()
    {
        int addXPos = Random.Range(0,4);
        Vector3 spawnPos = gameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(addXPos, 0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        ob = Instantiate(item[Random.Range(0, 5)],spawnPos,Quaternion.identity);
        Repeat();
    }
    void Repeat()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Inst());
    }

}
```

Также есть невидимый GameObject под сценой с Box Collider.

```
    public class triggerDetect : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, чтоб элемент префаба, который вошел в триггер, удалился, чтобы не засорять сцену одинаковыми объектами.

**UPD:**
Забыл отметить, что у меня 2D проект. Как решил: `OnTriggerEnter => OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)`. Все заработало!

Я новичок в Unity и в C# в целом, не обессудьте.

Comment: что не работает? скрипт висит,  дестрой написан. Разве что написать OnTriggerEnter

Comment: Вообще я использовал OnTriggerEnter, не работало, попробовал с OnTriggerExit.

Comment: так что не работает тогда?

Comment: Сам объект не удаляется, хотя на нем висит Rigidbody

Comment: замени `OnTriggerExit` на `OnTriggerEnter` и напиши внутри банально `Debug.Log("я тут");` и проверь, работает ли он.

Comment: А что значит `невидимый GameObject` ? А также у `Box Collider` нажат чекбокс `isTrigger`?

Comment: То есть пустой. isTrigger отмечен.

Comment: ширина высота установлены? дебаг выдает сообщение или нет?

Comment: Сейчас пока доступа к ПК нет, ещё не пробовал. Отпишусь потом.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у объекта со вторым скриптом, у коллайдера не стоит галочка "`IsTrigger`". Проставь эту галочку, тогда в скрипт начнет обрабатывать объекты. Если эта галочка не стоит, юнити считает коллизию более сложной, которую надо обрабатывать в методах `OnCollisionEnter`/`OnCollisionExit`

[image: IsTrigger]

**Обновление**

Есть ещё один вариант. Например, ваш префаб - пустой `GameObject`, внутри которого находится другой объект, с коллайдером. Тогда находящийся внутри объект будет уничтожен, но его родитель останется в игровом мире и будет его засорять.

[image: уничтожается только сам объект, не его родитель]

Comment: Is Trigger стоит

Comment: Я сделал сцену с вашими скриптами. Они работают. Значит, вы забыли какую то мелочь. Например, у префаба спавнящихся объектов нет Rigidbody , или коллайдера. Поймайте спавнящийся объект на паузе и проинспектируйте его.  В общем, OnTrigger не вызовется при любом из следующих условий: нет ни у одного из сталкивающихся объектов RigidBody, нет коллайдеров у одного из объектов, ни у одного из коллайдеров не стоит галочка IsTrigger